# Using webpack with require module on client side Javascript in NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/simple?_k=cycbjp) for creating a redux form in my NodeJS application. I put the code in my client side Javascript file and tried to run my application but I got a "require is not defined error". I'm using webpack to compile my Javascript file, which this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) suggested, so I'm not sure how I would go about using the require module on the client side.  Is there a step I'm missing in order to be able to use the require module?

These are the lines in my client.js file that are causing the error:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
```

This is what I have in webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var React = require('react');
var redux = require('redux');


var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/client.js',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
};


module.exports = config;
```

Comment: `target: 'node',` --- so, are you targeting `nodejs` or browsers?

Comment: could i target both? like use require in both browser and nodejs? For now using redux, I am trying to target browser

Comment: Just remove `target` thing at all then.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: You don't have your babel configured at the moment, have you? What is its config then?

Comment: You mean my .babelrc?  all i have is  {
 "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}

Comment: Paste the transpiled code somewhere then.

Comment: you mean my bundle.js? here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/88ahpjtz/

Comment: I don't see any `require()` call there.

Comment: it's at the very bottom,  module.exports = require("react");

Comment: Now remove `externals: [nodeExternals()],` and check https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Comment: thanks, that fixed the error. Any ideas why the redux form isn't showing up on my page tho?

Comment: Well, there is not enough information to help diagnosing those. Like - how do you bootstrap react

Comment: All i did was transfer the code from http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/simple?_k=cycbjp over to my client.js and included the scripts for react and react-dom in my index.html, i also have the react, react-dom, redux and redux-form node modules. Not getting any errors and just followed the tutorial so I'm confused as to why the form isn't showing up